# Overruled despite being given authority

Tags: job-description

I work at a place that has what is called a matrix organization. At various layers above me, there are Chief Engineers or Architects. For the sake of this, I am a mid tier Platform Architect. I have pushed for and received what is called an RAA or Roles Responsibility and Authority document. It basically lays out what is my job. Routinely, I may be overruled because another group disagrees either due to capacity or otherwise with a process, procedure or technical decision. Despite having receiving same approval from these Chief Engineer or Architect types to operate or proceed to execute in this manner. They signed off.

When approached, the response I get is that while they agree, they do not want to jeopardize the software release due to schedule. These are usually issues dealing with lack of configuration management or software security. We have clear processes stating when vulnerabilities for example should be resolved. Teams run out of capacity to resolve these items and appeal to higher authority to more or less cause me to be overruled.

How do I retain my RAA despite being occasionally outranked?

Comment: "How do I retain my RAA despite being occasionally outranked?"  You want to know how to not be overruled by persons with greater authority than you at your company?

Comment: Either you are asking on how to have absolute authority over your specific domain (which - spoiler alert - isn't going to happen in your position), or you're going to have to amend this question in a way that it doesn't ask how to have absolute authority.

Answer (score 11):

> Routinely, I may be overruled because another group disagrees either due to capacity or otherwise with a process, procedure or technical decision.

It seems you are surprised that when you make a decision, it runs into "lack of ____". The root of your problem is that you were surprised. If you want to retain your authority, formally or informally, involve these other parties in your decision making earlier on. Initiate routine meetings with these decision-makers, not just the chiefs. Chiefs are not perfect and do not have all the details in mind all the time; lower tier employees hopefully will.

Answer (score 11):

##### Your decisions affect other groups

You seem surprised that these other groups also have authority in the company.  Your title doesn't magically give you knowledge of every other connecting part of the process.  You haven't been "over-ridden," you're part of a team with an objective.  Understand your place in that team and you will be the better for it.